# Angular material is reseting my Y axis and making bottom 0px point to me bottom of window instead of bottom of document

Tags: css, angular-material

I have a sticky footer at my website and it was working great with bootstrap. Recently I've added angular-material dependency to my project and for some reason it is transforming my Y Axis, so when I do:

```
.page-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: url('../media/img/liteme/barra-degrade-inferior-1.png') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My footer is not placed at the bottom of document, it's instead place at the bottom of the window, the picture is as follows
[image]

Comment: maybe you need to add position:relative to the document container (if i understand the issue correctly

Comment: Didn't work :( footer is still on the same place

Comment: could you add a jsfiddler? https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/348/

Comment: @omer: done it, used same link you provided me, thanks: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1409/

Comment: You could say I can just remove position: absolute e bottom: 0 px, but the problem with that is when the page does not have content enough to fill window in height, then the footer is in the middle of the page

Comment: try using position:fixed instead of absolute

Comment: If I use it as fixed the footer not only overflows the content behind it but it also doesn't work as a sticky footer, I want it just to be shown at the end of page.

Comment: ok, i understand, try to set the parent as display:table and the footer as  display: table-row;vertical-align: bottom;

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, it worked, do you have the explanation for why did that happen? Also, don't you want to put an answer so I can mark you as correct?

Comment: great! yes ill add an answer and a link to an article about display table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am familiar with 3 ways to set footer at the bottom:

1.if you know the container height always going to be 100% then

- parent: `position:relative`
- footer: `position:absolute;bottom:0;`

2.if you don't know the container height is always 100% and don't mind if the footer float when page is being scrolled then

- parent: `position:relative;`
- footer: `position:fixed;bottom:0;`

3.if you don't know the container height is always 100% and do mind the floating footer with scroll then

- parent: `display:table;`
- footer: `display: table-row;vertical-align: bottom;`

for more information about the third option you can read this article https://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero#sticky-footer